# Convert drawings in instructions for Java Swing paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, drawing, paintcomponent, pacman

Would you know a software able to convert simple drawings (done with simple instructions that can be found in paintComponent like fillRectangle, drawLine... etc) into Java instructions?

I ask this question because I'm programming a Pacman game, and i wanted to be able to randomly generate ghosts, with random color, and shapes.

Thank you.

Comment: I've no idea what specifically you're asking for other than what sounds like might be an outside library, something that is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Instead perhaps you will want to code your own library to do what you want. If so, this is a multi-step process that will require you to break the large problem down into much smaller steps and then you will need to solve each problem one at a time.

Comment: You may be looking for a class that `implements Icon`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20implements%20Icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `Polygon` class. You can create `Shapes` by specifying `Points`:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(0, 0);
triangle.addPoint(15, 30);
triangle.addPoint(30, 0);
g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
g2d.fill( triangle );
```

The `fill(...)` method then just draws lines from one point to another to create the `Shape` and fill in the color. You can also use the `draw(...)` method to get the outline of the `Shape`.

You can also check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). It allows you to use the Shape as an Icon or even a component.